# Unable to print with lpr command

Tags: printing

I can't print with the `lpr` command even though I can print without the use of command line.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: In general, please could you copy and paste text from your terminal into your question and format it as code using the `{}` button, instead of posting a screenshot? Text is searchable and copyable, unlike an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set one of these printers to be default.

At your example, system detected two printers, appointing to same device:

```
- HP-PSC-1550-series
- PSC-1500-series
```

To pick one as the default lpd printer, type at the terminal

```
~$ lpoptions -d HP-PSC-1500-series
~$ lpq
```

to see if the printer you selected is now the default.

If these commands didn't work, you may edit /etc/cups/printers.conf.

```
sudo systemctl stop cups
sudo nano /etc/cups/printers.conf
```

Supposing you will find it here below as sample:

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v2.2.2
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<Printer HP-PSC-1550-series>
UUID xxxxx...
Info HP-PSC-1550-series
....
</Printer>
<Printer PSC-1550-series>
UUID xxxxx...
Info PSC-1550-series
....
</Printer>
```

Change at your default Printer tags:

`<Printer></Printer>`

by

`<DefaultPrinter></DefaultPrinter>`

Save this file and

```
sudo systemctl start cups.
```

After that, it's possible to print by line-command.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which printer to use. Either use `lpr -P HP-PSC-1500-series ...`, or set one of them (it? They have the same `serial=`. Confusion warning!), or set one as the System Default Printer, either via command line:

```
sudo lpoptions -d HP-PSC-1500-series
```

Or by using the CUPS web interface:

Open `http://localhost:631` in a browser, then navigate to `http://localhost:631/printers/HP-PSC-1500-series` (You will be prompted for a username/password along the way. Enter your login userid and password).

In the `Administration` drop-down, select `Set As Server Default`, then click `Go`.